# Javascript Get Page Source (server-side)

Tags: javascript, resources

Is it possible to get the source of a server-side page from a javascript script? I want to be able to get the source of a page that is in the same folder on the server. Is it possible without using anything other than javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want to get the result of the execution of some server side script (often HTML) from javascript you could use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).
- If you want to get the source code of some server side script using javascript (such as the C#, Java, PHP, ... code), you can forget about it unless you publish this source code as text file so that the server doesn't try to interpret it and then use AJAX to fetch this text file from javascript. Of course anyone will be able to access it, not only javascript hosted on your site.

Comment: Actually, it is a text file, but with a random extension. So can I do that without AJAX, or is it the only way?

Comment: Why would you want a different way?

Comment: Don't know.. I guess this is the answer for now, since it's the only one :l